# Prolog Predicates Exam Questions

Tags: prolog

I'm studying for an Artificial Intelligence exam and struggling to understand how to answer certain questions focusing on Predicates. The two questions in particular are:

1. Define a predicate which behaves as follows -

   ```
   ?- stage_name(billie, Name).

   Name = rose

   yes

   ?- stage_name(jenna,Name).

   Name = clara

   yes
   ```
2. Write a predicate that takes two argument and is true if both actors are on the same show.  Thus

   ```
   ?-same_show(david,clara).
   ```

   is true, whilst

   ```
   ?-same_continent(elisabeth,skippy).
   ```

   is not

I don't really understand how I would answer these questions, and I'm finding very little Prolog information online. I would appreciate some help. Apologies for the formatting.

Comment: I don't get the connection between same_show and same_continent. Is one only true if the other is not?

Comment: Very little Prolog information online? What exactly did you search for? There are [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=learn%20prolog%20now&oq=learn%20prolog%20now&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2135j0j7), [99 prolog problems, with answers](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/), etc.

Comment: The requirements you show could all be met just by declaring three facts: `stage_name(billie, rose).`, `stage_name(jenna, clara).` and `same_show(david, clara).`. Without any additional information about the requirements on the predicates, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

1:

```
stage_name(billie,rose).
stage_name(jenna,Name)  :- Name=clara.
```

**Explanation:**

Given a query, Prolog looks for an appropriate predicate according to the input parameters and the name and "executes" it. The result is either `true`/`false` if no output parameter is given. In this case there is one (`Name`) which can be seen from the leading capital letter. Note that there are two possible ways to implement this. The former is probably the most common (predicates of this form are called "facts" whereas predicates such as the lower are called "rules").

2:

As mentioned in my comment, I don't really understand the connection between the two given predicates. Also it feels like there is something missing such as a facts that determine which person is on which show...

Assuming such facts are missing, I would write the Prolog program as follows:

```
onShow(david, s1).
onShow(clara, s1).
onShow(bernie, s2).

same_show(P1, P2) :- onShow(P1,X), onShow(P2,X).
```

**Explanation:**

The predicate is only true if both `P1` and `P2` visit the same show `X`.

**Hints:**

- <s>A "comma" represents a logical AND operator. Having different rules with the same name and parameter count represents logical OR.</s> **Edit:** As Boris mentioned in a comment, this is not exactly true. This association simply helped me to understand the connection between "Logical Predicates" and "Prolog Predicates".
- Visit [SWISH](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) to test your Prolog programs.

Comment: why `stage_name(billie, Name) :- Name = rose.` and not simply `stage_name(billie, rose).`?

Comment: A "comma" is not a logical AND operator, it is a Prolog conjunction. It is not quite the same. But then the part about the OR is very wrong. A disjunction in Prolog is very different from a logical OR.

Comment: Yeah you're right. That was just the association that helped me understanding Prolog when I was about to learn it. I'll rethink that part

Comment: It might be easier to think about what a conjunction and a disjunction do to the search tree of a Prolog program (hint: a conjunction is an arch, the disjunction is a branching).